# gitlab api isn't returning project owner info

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to determine which projects belong to which divisions within our organization by retrieving the owner of each project and cross-referencing them back in active directory.  The gitlab API is giving me some trouble and I get inconsistent data.  Not all projects are giving me the owner information, yet I can see it from the website on the ones that don't. My account is an admin and my access token has all the read privileges.

```
https://gitlab.website.com/api/v4/projects/?access_token=<my_token>
```

I'm not sure why some projects provide that info through the api and some don't.  Of the 2577 projects, only 975 return the owner information.

I've compared some of the projects trying to see what might be different between them but I can't find anything.

Comment: What GtiLab version are you running? Is it that it used to include owner information but now doesn't, or in the same request some have the owner and some don't? From what I can see, the owner information was removed from the "List All Projects" response in version 15.2. That MR is [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/90989). The docs for [15.1 and higher](https://docs.gitlab.com/15.1/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) have the owner information present, but [15.2 and later](https://docs.gitlab.com/15.2/ee/api/projects.html#list-all-projects) do not.

Comment: Note: the MR above is the change to the docs. In it, the author states the API was changed some time prior, and they were updating the docs after the fact. I wasn't able to find the change to the API, mostly since I'm not too familiar with ruby/rails.

Comment: I'm 15.2. It'll be in the same request, simply some projects have the info and some do not. I'm not sure what version we started with, it's been upgraded over the years. So I'm wondering if this information wasn't stored for the api calls depending on what version we were on at the time the project was created?

Comment: It's possible, but I don't think that's in. In the postgres db it has the owner information stored or in some way associated with the project since as you saw, you can always see it in the UI. This sounds like a bug, and I'd open an Issue with GitLab for them to look into it.